# Maintaining number of row and columns in raster after clipping?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, clip

I have a DEM raster (WGS-1984) and MODIS scenes (1200*1200 pixels). I want to clip the DEM raster based on these scenes and after that create a new raster based on MODIS scenes bounds which has value at clipped part and no value at other areas which the DEM can not cover. At the final stage I want to have a raster with 1200*1200 rows and columns. I used clip and extract by mask from arc map (I checked maintain clip extension) but my final output has different number of rows and columns in contrast with MODIS. It is to be noted that MODIS scenes has the following coordinate information:

```
"Unknown_datum_based_upon_the_custom_spheroid_Sinusoidal
Authority: Custom

Projection: Sinusoidal
false_easting: 0.0
false_northing: 0.0
central_meridian: 0.0
Linear Unit: Meter (1.0)

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_Unknown_datum_based_upon_the_custom_spheroid
Angular Unit: Degree (0.0174532925199433)
Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0.0)
Datum: D_Not_specified_based_on_custom_spheroid
  Spheroid: Custom_spheroid
    Semimajor Axis: 6371007.181
    Semiminor Axis: 6371007.181
    Inverse Flattening: 0.0"
and DEM has the following coordinate information:"GCS_WGS_1984
WKID: 4326 Authority: EPSG

Angular Unit: Degree (0.0174532925199433)
Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0.0)
Datum: D_WGS_1984
  Spheroid: WGS_1984
    Semimajor Axis: 6378137.0
    Semiminor Axis: 6356752.314245179
    Inverse Flattening: 298.257223563"
```

[image: Data]